# AttributeError: module 'xml' has no attribute 'parsers'

Tags: ros2, rviz, urdf, ros-humble, tf

I try to visualize turtlebot2 urdf in ros2 humble by following the command `ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=turtlebot2.urdf`. I source my both workspace `source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash` & `ros2_ws` and also done `sudo apt install ros-humble-urdf*` but still get the following error

```
display.launch.py model:=turtlebot2.urdf
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/dell/.ros/log/2024-01-11-18-57-33-817547-ubuntu22-24635
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executed command failed. Command: xacro /opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot2.urdf
Captured stderr output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1012, in parse
    inp = f = open(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot2.urdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1119, in _process
    doc = process_file(input_file_name, **opts)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1096, in process_file
    doc = parse(None, input_file_name)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1016, in parse
    raise XacroException(e.strerror + ": " + e.filename, exc=e)
xacro.XacroException: No such file or directory: /opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot2.urdf [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot2.urdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/bin/xacro", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('xacro==2.0.8', 'console_scripts', 'xacro')())
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1171, in main
    _process(input_file_name, vars(opts))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/xacro/__init__.py", line 1124, in _process
    except xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError as e:
AttributeError: module 'xml' has no attribute 'parsers'
```

Answer (score 0):

"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot2.urdf'"

Did you try from the folder in which you have turtlebot2.urdf

run the following command:
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=/path_to_your_urdf_file/turtlebot2.urdf

path_to_your_urdf_file= go to the folder where the turtlebot2.urdf file is.

$pwd

and copy the exact path from there

Answer (score 0):

Some things to make sure of :

- Check if you have `xacro` installed : `sudo apt-get install ros-humble-xacro`
- If you have the URDF file in your own ROS package, check that you have added the URDF directory to be copied over when you build. To do that, check the `<package_name>_description/CMakeLists.txt` and in the install section, verify that you have added the URDF directory
- Check that the file `turtlebot2.urdf` is indeed present in your package install location. This is something that strikes me, because I took a look at the [source of the pacakge](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/tree/ros2/urdf), and I could not find a file named turtlebot.urdf. Maybe you are referring to a wrong package?

> xacro /opt/ros/humble/share/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot2.urdf
> Captured stderr output: Traceback (most recent call last):

This line tells us that the xacro program itself failed to parse the URDF. So, maybe you have a malformed xacro file, take a look at the source xacro file to make sure.

**NOTE**: A trick that comes in handy while writing a xacro file is to periodically verify that the xacro tool can parse it and generate a valid URDF. To do this, go to your description package, and call the xacro tool directly on the file itself. If you have a file called `turtlebot.xacro` in your <package_name>/xacro directory, you can do : `xacro xacro/turtlebot.xacro` from the root of your package, and see if xacro can indeed parse it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [xacro_live](https://github.com/orise-robotics/xacro_live) package which helps me a lot while creating my URDF.

Because the original did not work with Humble I created a pull request.

Hope this helps.